# Separating date and time from a timestamp, then combining later

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to take the time of day out of a 1 unix timestamp, the date(day, month, year) out of a different unix timestamp, and them combine those two into a new timestamp. However my timestamp foo seems to be failing. Could anyone offer some advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [date](http://php.net/date) function to extract the parts you need from your timestamps. Recombine the parts into a string with date and time and use [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) to convert it all back to a timestamp.

```
strtotime(sprintf('%s %s',
                  date('Y-m-d', $timestamp2),
                  date('H:i',   $timestamp1)));
```